# Elastalert not reading hits

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

[image: running elastalert in cmd]
[image: Kibana view of data]
I'm working on the use of elastalert to alert on getting data of a particular nature or frequency.
Please see my elastalert rule .yaml file.

```
            # Alert when the rate of events exceeds a threshold

            # (Optional)
            # Elasticsearch host
            es_host: localhost

            # (Optional)
            # Elasticsearch port
            es_port: 9200

            # (OptionaL) Connect with SSL to Elasticsearch
            #use_ssl: True

            # (Optional) basic-auth username and password for Elasticsearch
            #es_username: someusername
            #es_password: somepassword

            # (Required)
            # Rule name, must be unique
            name: my_rule

            # (Required)
            # Type of alert.
            # the frequency rule type alerts when num_events events occur with timeframe time
            type: any
            #frequency

            # (Required)
            # Index to search, wildcard supported
            index: shakes*

            # (Required, frequency specific)
            # Alert when this many documents matching the query occur within a timeframe
            num_events: 1

            # (Required, frequency specific)
            # num_events must occur within this amount of time to trigger an alert
            timeframe:
              seconds: 15

            # (Required)
            # A list of Elasticsearch filters used for find events
            # These filters are joined with AND and nested in a filtered query
            # For more info: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html
            filter: []
            #- query:
            #   query_string: 
            #      query: "play_name: Henry IV"

            # (Required)
            # The alert is use when a match is found
            alert:
            - "email"

            # (required, email specific)
            # a list of email addresses to send alerts to
            email:
            - "olawi@vg.com"
```

The hits ought to count. I get no hits. Now, I saw a similar post, where the dev was asked to adjust the time, as elastalert works based on the browser's time. I adjusted my system time to match that of the timestamp of the docs in my index but still it is not giving any hits for the time period.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Search, Kibana and ELastAlert by default work on UTC. So ElastAlert will be querying your ES basis UTC. Request you to follow below points.

- Please check which time zone your kibana is
  using(since you are using Kibana to check hits). You can do so by
  **Management Tab ->Advance Settings ->dateFormat:tz**. If it's not UTC, please change it to UTC and then compare with ElastAlert. This
  shall get you the hits if there are any. (Assuming you have not
  specified other time zone in your ES schema. If done, change Kibana
  time zone to that of ES to check hits)
- If the timezone is different from UTC in your ES, please follow [this
  issue](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/1047) for the solution.
- Also, you can check your ES query that ElastAlert is using to make
  sure desired date time filter in going in your query.  You can do so
  by changing logging level of ElastAlert. Please follow [this](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html?highlight=logging#running-elastalert) to
  do so.

Thanks